# "from the level of individual" vs. "on the level of individual"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Which is correct? This is important because it's the closing sentence of my entire thesis, so I must get it grammatical.

> **1)** ''
>   The motivation for many of these suggestions is the detail that can be achieved by approaching the
>   question ***from*** the level of individual constituents.''
>
> **2)** ''
>   The motivation for many of these suggestions is the detail that can be achieved by approaching the
>   question ***on*** the level of individual constituents.''

Comment: They're both grammatical. Only the semantics are in question. I'd say either **from** or **at** (not _on_). I might even change the wording to say "**from the _perspective_ of individual constituents**". But that's without my knowing anything else about your thesis, so it may not be a good suggestion. "_Level_" suggests class distinctions, and we know that there's none o'that in the USA.

Comment: You're so good!

Comment: Are you sure you mean *individual constituents* instead of *from the level of the individual constituent*? The singular construction is often used to imply the group, and it allows the singular *level* to be used without any ambiguity: no one will be confused whether you are trying to imply that all constituents share a single level.

Comment: @Robusto All constituents do share a singular *level*. Given this, does there still exist a problem?

Comment: Seems to me that "_{from/at} **the level** of the individual constituents_" implies a single level for all, but that "_{from/at} **the levels** of the individual constituents_" would be problematic because it implies many different levels.

Comment: @Jase: If they do share a single level, I don't see a problem. This is a matter of style. That said, I myself would still prefer *from the level of the individual constituent*.

Comment: What @Bill said in the first comment. To be honest, whichever preposition is used, I don't actually understand exactly what *"level"* is supposed to mean here. I can make sense of *"from the **perspective**"*, but not OP's version. My best guess is it's supposed to mean *"The motivation...is the detail [available] at the level of details"*, which doesn't have a lot going for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a spatial metaphor: neither *from* nor *on* sorts very felicitously with *approach*. It is the “constituents” which occupy a particular “level”; with *approach* what you are proposing is to move *from* your ‘position’ to the ‘position’ occupied by the question *by way of* the *[level of] individual constituents*.
2. Unless you are an Aristotelian speaking of “final cause”, I don’t think you can speak of *detail* as the *motivation* for your suggestions; *motivation* generally denotes *efficient cause*. What motivates your  suggestions is not the detail but the ***desire to achieve*** that detail.

I’d rewrite something like this:

> “Many of these suggestions are prompted by the prospect of achieving a much higher level of detail through approaching the general question by way of  its individual constituents.”